# Select with variable LIMIT value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a comments table. Every single comment could be a response to another comment.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE comments
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    content text,
    root integer NULL,
    date_added timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

I need to select the newest 10 threads with their responses, so in result I may have for example 10 threads and 8 responses. I'm not sure hot to do that. I've tried:

```
SELECT content FROM comments 
ORDER BY date_added DESC 
LIMIT 10 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMMENTS WHERE root IS NOT NULL)
```

But this has no proper effect.

Comment: simple example of input data and desired output data could help. Do you need all responses down to the tree?

Comment: Yes, I need whole tree limited to 10 by threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure is that what you want, but looks like recursive cte could help you:

```
with recursive cte as (
    -- anchor of the query - last 10 threads
    select c.id, c.content 
    from comments as c
    where c.root is null -- top level threads
    order by c.date_added desc
    limit 10

    union all

    -- recursively get all children
    select c.id, c.content
    from comments as c
        inner join cte as cr on cr.id = c.root
)
select
    content
from cte
```

Comment: This is pretty what I need. As far I know using LIMIT with UNION requires brackets added at start and end of queries.